# Hard drive from ultrasound machine will not allow me to copy image files to USB

Tags: hard-drive, usb, usb-flash-drive

I have an ultrasound machine with a USB port so I can copy image files to be viewed on a PC. In the first few years, any USB I plugged in was able to copy files. Recently, the machine will not allow the files to be copied to a USB unless it had previously been used. I have one that I continuously use and can then transfer files to a new USB flash drive, however I only have one that will work (all the others were given to clients years ago) and I am in constant fear of losing it or having it get damaged. Could the machine possibly apply some type of formatting to the flash drive that, after multiple new flash drives being used can no longer accept new ones? If it does, would there a way to reset the hard drive so it will recognize and accept new USB flash drives. When I ask these questions to the IT department at the company I purchased the machine from, they stare at me with blank eyes. I'm not sure if my question just doesn't make sense or if they are just oblivious to what is causing my problem. I just came across this website on a random Google search and the answers given to some of the other questions seemed like some of you experts are a little (a lot) more savvy than the people I've dealt with in the past. Doesn't hurt to ask, I guess!

Comment: Have you asked this question of the manufacturer of the machine?  That seems to be the best place to start.

Comment: what is the make/model/size of the USB that works? How it formatted (i.e. FAT16? FAT32? Something else?) does the USB drive have partitions - this may be a false memory, but I recall many thumb drives used to be partitionless - but, as I said, could be a false memory

Comment: @John They already did according to the question. Now, it can have something to do with formatting but not the way you're imagining it. Probably the machines expects FAT32 and if you're using the now ubiquitous bigger drives (64GB+) most, if not all came formatted as exFAT. I suggest you try again with a FAT32 formatted one. However, if really old then you may need to use FAT16 instead but that's quite unlikely.

Comment: For all we know it may for example support FAT16 while you try to feed it FAT32, or support FAT32 while you insert exFAT formatted flash drives. It may even not support above a certain device capacity.

Comment: @Bravo They would have a unique partition, and Windows makes it hard to create more than one, though I think the built-in commande line tool "dispkpart".

Comment: Thank you for the input. It has been almost 6 months since I spoke with the manufacturer. I will try them again and present them with the suggestions many of you have provided to see if someone might be able to figure it out. I greatly appreciate your time and input!

Answer (score 2):

For all we know it may for example support FAT16 while you try to feed it FAT32, or support FAT32 while you insert exFAT formatted flash drives. It may even not support above a certain device capacity.

If you have the ultrasound machine's model number it may be something that's documented and that can be found online.

Or, determine file system the drive that works was formatted with (In Windows right click drive > Properties), get a similar size USB flash drive and format with that file system and try if the ultrasound is happy with it.

Answer (score -1):

First, try what others said, check the file system used, and the drive size.

If that does not help you solve your issue, your ultrasound machine may have some "bizarre" way of handling store.

You can then look into doing a bit-level duplicate of your flash drive onto another (as similar as possible) one. It needs to be as large or larger (it's not entirely necessary, but it'll make your like much easier).

You can perform such a copy using a tool like "dd".

Note that once that is done, it is quite possible that plugging both drives at the same time on your computer will cause problems, so use only one at a time.